# How to create a file like the MNIST dataset

Tags: java, mnist

So i have a bunch of images (PNG) and their names can be used as labels. Is there a tool or an example on how i can take those images and create a dataset like the MNIST IDX one.

There are a lot of examples on how to read them but no examples on how to create them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help.

> The -images- files were written using the function save-idx3-ubyte and the -labels- files with the function save-idx1-ubyte. The functions in questions are defined in lush/lsh/libidx/idx-io.lsh The file format is described in the section "IDX file format for  compilable I/O" which is under "standard libraries" -> "Tensor/Matrix/Scalar/Vector  libraries" -> "IDX reading and writing".
>
> The 32-bit ints in the header of the files may be byte-swapped.

-- Yann

http://sourceforge.net/p/lush/mailman/message/28879896/

Comment: Im sorry i shelved that project, I just dont have enough time at the moment to work on it. I will post the code once i have it.

Comment: Is there an R or Python solution that does the same thing? I would also like to create a .gz file like the MNIST data from a bunch of images.